# How to explictly tell python install commands which python to use?

Tags: python

I'm having a mess of problems trying to install python modules with pip using a local version of python/pip installed in my home directory.  First, this should prove my PATH variable is set correctly:

```
command -v python
    /home/myuserid/PYTHON4/bin/python
command -v python
    /home/myuserid/PYTHON4/bin/pip
```

I then try to install python modules with pip.  Some modules install successfully.  But one named matlabplot is giving me problems.  Specifically, I run

```
pip install matplotlib --target=/home/myuserid/PYTHON4/PYTHON
```

The errors are

```
Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-VwF2LG/subprocess32/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-pj2g8u-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --home=/tmp/tmplDhrIG:
....
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _posixsubprocess.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_posixsubprocess.o
_posixsubprocess.c:16:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include "Python.h"
```

There are two problems with that error message:

- First, it is using /usr/local/bin/python.  This is the wrong python (I previously installed python there).  Where is that coming from?  It's not on my path.  If I print my entire environment with printenv, it's not listed anywhere.
- Second, the gcc compile command explictly includes "-I/usr/include/python2.7" on the command line.  That should not happen because I'm trying to use a local python that is installed in/p/home/myuserid/PYTHON4.

I'm guessing the cause is I'm somehow not specifying where python is installed.  How can I fix these problems?

Answer (score 0):

Avoid `pip install`, prefer `python -m pip install`. This way you're telling explicitly you want to use the `python` program for which you checked the path. And you can play many variations around it:

- `python3 -m pip install`
- `/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install`
- `python3.9 -m pip install`
- ...

About the numpy issue, it's because `pip` don't find an already compiled `numpy` for your platform. It may be because you're running an old version or `pip`, so you can first try a `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`, and try installing numpy again.

You can also take a look at https://pypi.org/simple/numpy, you'll see a list of files like:

```
numpy-1.21.2-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
numpy-1.21.2-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl
numpy-1.21.2-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_12_i686.manylinux2010_i686.whl
```

the `whl` files are pre-compiled ones, but for specific platforms and specific Python versions, here the 3 wheels I listed are for numpy 2.21.2, for cpython 3.9, for windows, macosx, and many linuxes.

Maybe your specific set of Python version / numpy version / platform is not pre-compiled here?

If you really need to let pip compile numpy you'll need some more dependencies, the missing `Python.h` one means you're missing the `python3-dev` package from your distrib.

Last hint: you should use a [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html): a venv is created by a specific version of Python, and all installations are done inside the venv (so easily removable: just remove the directory, in case it goes badly).